# Forward an email account while keeping other email accounts in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

My organization has several different companies with several domains and we're using Exchange 2007 to handle all the emails.  One of my colleagues has several different email accounts which he accesses through Outlook.  Let's suppose his email address are: david@company1.com, david@company2.com, david@company3.com etc

I want to forward email from david@company2.com to someone@company2.com but leave all his other email accounts intact.  Also, I don't want to remove or delete any history from Outlook for any emails he received on david@company2.com.  I'm using Exchange 2007 and Windows Server 2003.  Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Sincerely,
Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone@company2.com is another Exchange account, then you can just change the SMTP address space from the "david@" account (david@company2.com) to be included in the "someone@" account's SMTP address space.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: How many Exchange servers are "in play" here and are they in separate domain/management spaces? You might check the Outlook configuration as needed to assist in that determination - the hint will be a single server service provider vs. multiples within the profile(s).